# window API for wireless mouse and keyboard

Tags: winapi

Is there any window API to catch the signals sent by the wireless mouse and keyboard ?
How far i know signals from this wireless device are always sent if it is connected but for the cabled mouse/keyboard , when we are moving  the device only for that time signals are being sent ..Please correct me if i am wrong ..

If above is the case then please let me know any API to catch the signals sent by the wireless mouse/keyboard ?

Comment: A comment on the msdn page indicates that from vista onwards BlockInput requires elevation so run it as administrator and see if it works, failing that examine the return code of GetLastError after the call.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any window API

The Windows API (which is a user-mode API) doesn't care what kind of mouse you have: serial port, USB, wireless...

The mouse hardware connection is handled in the kernel, by a device driver.

Comment: i have used BlockInput(true)..But its not working under win 7 . Is there any other way to block the user i/p ?

Comment: @vivek I don't know: you'd better ask that as a separate question (or edit your existing question, if that's what you're asking).

Comment: so whether i/p devices are always sending signals(if connected) irrespective of whether it is wireless or not ?